# Mathematical explanation of the usage of monads to wrap data for avoiding errors

Tags: haskell, monad

For the past two days I have been on a question to understand monads in the context of Haskell. A nice explanation I found is by Graham Hutton on the Computerphile channel [see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1e8gqXLbsU&pp=ygUGbW9uYWRz). This explanation has also been paraphrased into [this nice answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28135478/17745723). It makes more or less perfect sense to me, but I am having difficulty matching this to the mathematical definition of a monad which I found nicely explained [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENo_B8CZNRQ), quoting the final part:

> A monad in X is a monoid in the category of endofunctors of X

So, far I know the category we are dealing with is the category Hask,

> The main category we'll be concerning ourselves with in this article is Hask, which treats Haskell types as objects and Haskell functions as morphisms and uses (.) for composition: a function f :: A -> B for types A and B is a morphism in Hask.- [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory)

Wikipedia defines monoid as a set with a binary operation having identity and associativity, but **I am failing to see how to use that definition to understand what's going on here.**

---

Now, I've seen this post here on CS SE by [Andrej Bauer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81591/how-is-the-definition-of-monads-in-category-theory-equivalent-to-the-definition) that we have to do a little work to get the equivalence, but could someone anyways try explaining the above in less abstract/ concrete terms for a total newb to understand?

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of a monoid in a category? The definition you mention is the standard one from abstract algebra, but categorically speaking we would say that it's specialized to the category of sets. See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoid) for a categorically minded discussion of the definition you mention, and [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoid+in+a+monoidal+category) for a discussion of the more categorical version. (generally speaking, nlab>wikipedia for category theory references)